# Interaction between Esix, Fractal Bloom and Forbidden Orchard

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Could I stop another player from ever creating more than one token for [Esix, Fractal Bloom](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Esix%2C%20Fractal%20Bloom) to affect on their turn by giving them the spirit in their upkeep from [Forbidden Orchard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Forbidden%20Orchard) or does it not count the token given to you?

Comment: Given the Oracle wording for Forbidden Orchard "target opponent creates a 1/1 colorless Spirit creature token" could you explain what you are finding difficult to understand here?

Answer (score 11):

If

1. your opponent controls Esix, Fractal Bloom
2. they have e.g. a sorcery to create a lot of tokens
3. they have a good creature to copy
4. you want to limit them to only one copy on their turn

then yes, you can activate Forbidden Orchard to do this. Esix does not care about who controlled the trigger, it only cares about who *created* the token, which in the case of Forbidden Orchard is your opponent.